# ROS Answers SE migration: Robots NXT

Tags: nxt, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS FUETE in my OS, Ubuntu 11.10, now I'm installing ROBOTS NXT with ROS,
I followed this web site ::: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/NXT/electric,
but I have problems with the command """rosrun nxt_python touch_sensor_test.py"""
in the section 1.7, the following error is shown:
iohan@iohan-HP-Compaq-8200-Elite-SFF-PC:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosrun nxt_python touch_sensor_test.py[rospack] Error: stack/package nxt_python not found

help,please!!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43782/robots-nxt/) by [Iohan Goncalves](https://answers.ros.org/users/3113/iohan-goncalves/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed ROS Fuerte, then you were probably able to install the nxt_all package; however, you installed Fuerte, not Electric (the most recent distribution that supports nxt). So, Fuerte cannot access the files, because they don't exist under your Fuerte install.

To verify that this is the circumstance:
`ls /opt/ros`

If I'm correct, you will see two directories output.

To fix this issue, install electric. Unfortunately, the nxt doesn't cooperate with Fuerte at the moment.

-Hunter A.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0